# Removing item from collection does not trigger remove event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection with a listener on the remove event.

```
this.listenTo(this.collectionFiltered, 'remove', this.render, this);
```

I pass this collection into a new view

```
var siteInfoView = new SiteInfoView({model: site, parentCollection: this.collectionFiltered});
```

and remove a model from it.

```
this.parentCollection.remove(this.model);
```

This doesn't seem to trigger the event handler, and I'm not sure why. I've verified the event doesn't fire by creating this listener:

```
this.listenTo(this.collectionFiltered, 'remove', function() {console.log('remove event');}, this);
```

I would have thought this is because I'm trying to trigger events across views, but I'm able to catch changes to a model passed into the second view from the first one. I know the event is firing on `this.collectionFiltered` from the first view because that view changes to reflect that the model has been removed.

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

**Update:** SiteInfoView initialize:

```
initialize: function(options){
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render, this);
    this.parentCollection = options.parentCollection || null;
},
```

**Update 2:** Gist of the two views: https://gist.github.com/raddevon/aea6b21226e90c6352ba

**Update 3:** [This Codepen](http://codepen.io/raddevon/pen/bdpMxG) was built to demonstrate the problem, but it works. There's obviously something I'm doing in my code that I'm just not seeing.

**Update 4:** Just discovered `monitorEvents` in Chrome DevTools. Monitored the collection in question and removed the item. No events were logged to the console in DevTools.

Comment: Every thing seems to be perfect here, can you show the code that handles options in initialize of view and possible provide a fiddle.

Comment: @ezpura Added the view's initialize. Trying to put together a fiddle that will demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @ezpura Having some problems getting a fiddle working. Can you tell anything from a gist with the full code of both views? https://gist.github.com/raddevon/aea6b21226e90c6352ba

Comment: @ezpura I thought I had replicated the circumstances of my issue in this Codepen, but it appears there's something I'm missing. Unlike my app, this demo works as I would expect. http://codepen.io/raddevon/pen/bdpMxG

Comment: Well every thing seems fine to me , try loging parentCollection and check may be the context of this is lost